# Groovy:Xml: How to read parsed xml string's text within a single loop

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, xmldocument

Have an xml string response which contain a child tag named `<Name>` ,the response may contain one or more `<Name>` tags  as given below,

Case 1

String Xml =`<School>
                    <Student>
                        <Name>Akhil</Name>
                        <Name>Nikhil</Name>
                        <Name>Kiran</Name>
                   </Student>
             <School>`

Case 2
String Xml =`<School>
                    <Student>
                        <Name>Akhil</Name>
                    </Student>
             <School>`

```
String parsedXml =  new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(Xml)
```

in case 1 value inside the first `<Name>` tag is obtained by using below statement

```
Case 1
     String name = parsedXml.Student.Name[0].text()
```

in case 2 value inside the `<Name>` tag is obtained by using below statement

```
Case 2
     String name = parsedXml.Student.Name.text()
```

So how can i get `value Akhil` ie: from first tag in both case by using one statement

```
String name = parsedXml.Student.Name[0].text()
```

if i use this statement in case 2: then an error as null

Answer (score 2):

You can use [spread-dot](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SpreadOperator%28%2a.%29) operator. It will access ALL child nodes with given name. It will return you a list, wich you can then flatten, if you have unregular xml structure with both tag cases inside.

```
String xml ="""<School>
  <Student>
    <Name>Akhil</Name>
    <Name>Nikhil</Name>
    <Name>Kiran</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <Name>Akhil2</Name>
  </Student>
</School>"""

def res = new XmlParser().parseText(xml).Student*.Name.flatten()*.text()
println(res) //[Akhil, Nikhil, Kiran, Akhil2]
```

**EDIT:**

This line will give you [Akhil, Akhil2] as output.

```
new XmlParser().parseText(xml).Student*.Name.collect { it[0] }*.text()
```

Comment: Actually what i want is to read the first tag's value only, don't need the whole list of names ie, [akhil] in first and second case and have to handle it seperatly...

Answer (score 0):

This way You'll always get a list:

```
def xml1 = '''<School>
                    <Student>
                        <Name>Akhil</Name>
                        <Name>Nikhil</Name>
                        <Name>Kiran</Name>
                   </Student>
             </School>'''

def xml2 = '''<School>
                    <Student>
                        <Name>Akhil</Name>
                    </Student>
             </School>'''
def xml1p = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(xml1)
def xml2p = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(xml2)

println xml1p.Student.Name*.text().first() //or [0]
println xml2p.Student.Name*.text().first() //or [0]
```

Comment: Actually what i want is to read the first tag's value only, don't need the whole list of names